# How to make a DB query in a Jira plugin?

Tags: jira-plugin

I'm writing a custom Jql function to execute an advanced query that is not possible with plain Jql. I need to find all issues with more than one component OR (exactly one component AND a given custom field not being null).

What Manager class can I inject in my plugin, so that I can issue an SQL, Hibernate or other kind of database query?

The aim is for my custom function to return a list of matching issues, so that it can be used in a Jql search in Jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out the JIRA API reference:
http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.1/com/atlassian/jira/jql/builder/JqlClauseBuilder.html
and
http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.1/com/atlassian/jira/jql/builder/ConditionBuilder.html

You can always create a method to your plugin class which looks like this:

```
public class MyPlugin
{
    JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext;
    SearchProvider searchProvider; 
    public MyPlugin(JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext, SearchProvider searchProvider){
        this.authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
        this.searchProvider = searchProvider; 
    }

    public List<Issue> getIssues(CustomField your_cf) throws SearchException{
        User user = authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser();

        JqlClauseBuilder jqb = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder().where();
        jqb = jqb.not().componentIsEmpty();
        Query query = jqb.endWhere().buildQuery(); 

        List<Issue> issues = searchProvider.search(query, user, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter()).getIssues();

        List<Issue> result = new ArrayList<Issue>(); 
        for(Issue issue : issues){
                Collection<GenericValue> components = issue.getComponents(); 
                //component size already > 0 from query
                if(components.size() > 1 || (issue.getCustomFieldValue(your_cf) != null)) 
                        result.add(issue); 
        }
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I believe my query is more complex that that and cannot be expressed in JQL (although I may be wrong). I've added parentheses to my question to clarify what's the problem.
If it could be expressed using the Jql API, I'd just write it in JQL itself in Jira. Instead I thought I could write a custom function plugin, to execute some custom SQL, but I'm having trouble accessing the DB layer from the plugin.

Comment: The problem is that Jql allows to express "no component" or "at least one component", but not "exactly one component" nor "more than one component", unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have misunderstand your condition. As you I haven't found a JQL condition for that so I fetched the issues in plugin class.

Comment: Not an answer... but alternative approach